# Add VueMapbox to Vue in a "normal" html page

Tags: vue.js, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add some Vue generated content to an existing website solution, so therefore I can´t "install" Vue and VueMapbox with NPM or the like. My setup is this (simplified): https://codepen.io/martin-bernt-rud/pen/QWgNprW

```
<div id="app">
  <MglMap
      :mapboxGl="mapbox-gl"
      :accessToken="accessToken"
      :mapStyle.sync="mapStyle"
      @load="onMapLoaded"
    />
</div>
```

---

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      MglMap
    },
    data: {
      accessToken: 'xxx',
      mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11'
    },
    created() {
        this.mapbox = Mapbox;
    }
})
```

How do I register "VueMapbox" (like in this bare bones example https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/guide/basemap.html...)?

Right now I get the error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: MglMap is not defined" (to be expected)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't include all your code, but you are probably missing a statement like:

```js
import MglMap from 'vue-mapbox';
```

Comment: That gives me:


Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue-mapbox". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". 

Isn´t because it´s 'stand alone' javascript and not in an NPM enviroment?

Comment: Sounds like you are not yet familiar with how NPM imports work, and may have some general beginner learning to do.